# Performance penalty of Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid, reflection.emit

I am considering a possible solution to an issue i'm working on (.NET 3.5 WinForms application).

In our app, we have many methods (C#) whose arguments are entered by the user of the application.

An example would be something like:

```
public void DoSomething(string name, DateTime date)
{
   // ...
}
```

Where name, date is currently entered using a simple textbox.
We would like to have the benefits of rich editors, password protected input boxes, autocomplete, and more.

I would like the user's input to be made using a *PropertyGrid*, however this control can only bind to an object, and not arguments.

I have read both excellent articles from MSDN magazine regarding the ProperyGrid:

[ICustomTypeDescriptor, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163816.aspx)

[ICustomTypeDescriptor, Part 2](http://ICustomTypeDescriptor,%20Part%202)

However this seems to be helpful in a scenario where the object that will be bound to the PropertyGrid is known in advance, which is not my case.

Can this scenario be supported? Is there any simple and easy to implement solution?

I thought of using Reflection.Emit to create a "temp" object at runtime, whose properties would be the method's arguments. 
I have never done this before (use of Reflection.Emit namespace) and i would like to know the performance penalty of using it? (does it actually compile the code at runtime in-memory or how does it work?)

Comment: What does stop you to use Expando object for such usages?

Comment: Edited my question - using 3.5, no Expando for us.

Comment: Then what about using a dictionary and call your method with Reflection API? I use same thing in our CMS for centralizing arbitrary web method calls to specific class methods.

Comment: Calling the method is not the issue. Letting the user enter the method's arguments through a PropertyGrid (or any other easy to use UI control) is the issue.

Comment: Can't you iterate through PropertyGrid items and collect the data which is provided by the user?

Comment: PropertyGrid binds to an Object instance. What i would want is to dynamically create some Object that has a property for each argument my method receives. An argument might be some other object type in itself, so this has to be taken into consideration as well...

Comment: I haven't played PropertyGrid at all. But, according to your information, I would create temporary object via Reflection. Caching temporary object could increase your performance. Some people uses same thing in .NET 3.5 instead of expando object. I can't see any other options. Some relevant sources are here: [1](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/dynamically-generating--typed-objects-in-.net/), [2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Dynamic_Code_Generation.aspx), [3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DynamicMethod_ILGenerator.aspx)

Comment: And last but not least, [here](http://typedescriptor.net/browse/types/22193-System.Web.Query.Dynamic.ClassFactory) is the code sample from .NET framework.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to do this (create a proxy type with properties corresponding to method parameters) using Reflection.Emit. Once you have this, you could assign an instance of the proxy object to your PropertyGrid, and then use the values entered to call the method.  What you want to do, however, is not trivial.

I would point you to the MSDN documentation for TypeBuilder for an example of creating a type using Reflection.Emit.

To answer your questions about performance, yes, the code is compiled "in memory".  What you would typically want to do is cache the generated type in a dictionary so it can be reused.  The biggest performance hit is on Type generation.  Creating an instance of the type can be made to be very cheap (depending on how you do it - Activator.CreateInstance() being the slowest, something like this:

```
private Func<T> GetCreator()
    {
        if (_Creator == null)
        {
            Expression body;
            var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            var defaultConstructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(bindingFlags, null, new Type[0], null);
            if (defaultConstructor != null)
            {
                // lambdaExpression = () => (object) new TClass()
                body = Expression.New(defaultConstructor);
            }
            else
            {
                // lambdaExpression = () => FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(classType)
                var getUnitializedObjectMethodInfo = typeof(FormatterServices).GetMethod("GetUninitializedObject", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
                body = Expression.Call(getUnitializedObjectMethodInfo, Expression.Constant(typeof(T)));
            }
            var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(body);
            _Creator = lambdaExpression.Compile();
        }
        return _Creator;
    }
```

which allows you to create a new instance by simply calling

```
object obj = GetCreator()();
```

Using this pattern, you'll see degraded performance when your application is just getting started, but as the cache misses decrease it will perform almost as good as inline code.

You can use a similar method for generating Invokers - there is a pretty good example here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FastMethodInvoker.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is more or less same problem and it's solution. It's written for .NET 3.5 and works well. The goal was centralize all web methods in a single web service (.asmx) and call any registered methods from a single location. The code could be much more smaller. But, due to some forced conversion, it's a bit long.

```
public object ExecuteMethod(string moduleName, string methodName, object[] arguments)
{
  CmsModuleMethodInfo methodInfo = CmsModuleManager.GetModuleMethod(moduleName, methodName);
  ...

  ParameterInfo[] paramInfo = methodInfo.Method.GetParameters();
  Object[] parameters = new Object[paramInfo.Length];
  Type[] paramTypes = paramInfo.Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; ++i)
  {
    Type paramType = paramTypes[i];
    Type passedType = (arguments[i] != null) ? arguments[i].GetType() : null;

    if (paramType.IsArray)
    {
      // Workaround for InvokeMethod which is very strict about arguments.
      // For example, "int[]" is casted as System.Object[] and
      // InvokeMethod raises an exception in this case.
      // So, convert any object which is an Array actually to a real Array.
      int n = ((Array)arguments[i]).Length;
      parameters[i] = Array.CreateInstance(paramType.GetElementType(), n);
      Array.Copy((Array)arguments[i], (Array)parameters[i], n);
    }
    else if ((passedType == typeof(System.Int32)) && (paramType.IsEnum))
    {
      parameters[i] = Enum.ToObject(paramType, (System.Int32)arguments[i]);
    }
    else
    {
      // just pass it as it's
      parameters[i] = Convert.ChangeType(arguments[i], paramType);
    }
  }

  object result = null;
  try
  {
    result = methodInfo.Method.Invoke(null, parameters);
  }
  catch (TargetInvocationException e)
  {
    if (e.InnerException != null)
    {
      throw e.InnerException;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Osman, if you are using reflection to invoke your methods you are taking a HUGE performance hit. You should consider (if you haven't already, something like FastMethodInvoker (www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FastMethodInvoker.aspx)

Comment: @Joe: Thanks! Actually we don't feel any slowness at all (web methods are not called that much). And what's more we're already moving to new code base in our product. So, it's more or less obsolete. But, knowing such a thing is clearly a good thing. Thanks again.